# I am trying to delay this function without using any built in Methods. Why wont this work?

Tags: javascript, methods, delay

```
function delay(func, wait){ 
var timer = new Date().getTime() + wait;
var end = new Date().getTime()
for(var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++){
if(timer === end){
    return func(arguments[2], arguments[3])
    }
else{
    end = new Date().getTime()
 }
 }
}
console.log(delay(function(first,second) { return first + second},500,200,300));
```

I have been messing with this for a while and havent figured out whats wrong. Also id there is any much simple way to do this let me know.

Comment: this is a good way to make an unresponsive web page, and the browser will most likely pause your script to ask the user if they want to continue running poorly written javascript

Comment: Yes it would but only if the timer never equals the end. If the timer equals end it will jump out of the loop.

Comment: the way you are calling the delay function, it will run once, with a delay of 500ms

Comment: okay thats what i want. thats weird its not working on my end.

Comment: Your code works fine - despite it being poor practice, it delays 500ms before logging 500

Comment: to paraphrase @JithuPRajan - why do you want to avoid setTimeout? Don't let asynchronous code scare you - embrace its wonder that will lead you to the Promise land

Comment: whats the best way to actually do this then without using setTimeout or any other methods

Comment: I just want to know the actual code behind setTimeout

Comment: console.log(window.setTimeout + '') - will show you that it's **native code** - and I can assure you there are no synchronous loops in it

Comment: `best way to actually do this then without using setTimeout or any other methods` - there are no good ways at all, but lets say what you posted is the possibly the least bad

Comment: rather than `for(var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)` - use `while(true)` and `return` out of it when time is up ...

Comment: Looping until some time occurs is nothing but a bad practice in JS.  Because the JS engine is single threaded, nothing else can run while you're in your loop.  No user event handlers, no other timers, no other I/O operations, no screen updates, nothing.  This is bad.  This is not how you write Javascript.  Embrace `setTimeout()` to schedule something to run at some time in the future and start learning how you actually write code in Javascript.  Don't fight it.  It's the way things work in JS - you need to learn it.

Comment: I completely agree with you. No doubt setTimeout is the best way to do this. Im just wondering why my code wont actually work in a web page.

Comment: *"I am trying to delay this function without using any built in Methods"* - But your code *does* use built-in methods. You are calling the `Date()` constructor function, and you also use the `.getTime()` method. Regarding your first comment above about the browser stopping the script, the browser doesn't do that only with infinite loops, it does it with "long-running" code blocks (where different browsers have their own definition of "long-running"), so if you specify to high a delay the user will get prompted to break out of it even though it would've eventually ended on its own.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve with this code? If you are trying to create some delay use setTimeout function.

Comment: this should be a comment :p

Comment: that comment looks funny, if you think about it - I know, you can probably comment on your own answer - I have no idea how the rules work :p

Comment: I am trying to delay the function without using any methods like setTimeout

Comment: If you  try to delay a function by using some loops, your page becomes unresponsive as mentioned by  @Jaromanda X

Comment: would this actually make it become unresponsive even though I am using return to jump out of the loop.